# Find Nth number in a long variable in vbnet

Tags: vb.net, long-integer

I have a very long number that goes like this:

```
numb as long=011212201220200112202001200101121220200120010112200101120112122....
```

It will be more than 4,000,000,000 digits. My problem is to find any digit in the number. If it was integer I would convert to string and do this:

```
numb(200)
```

But his is **Long**. Do you know how to find this?

Comment: You could us an array: `Dim digits As Long = 4000000000   Dim numb(digits) As Integer`. You can then access with `numb(200)`

Comment: Still on your CodeEval? So obviously you managed the first problem. If one of the comments or an answer did help you, please mark it at answer. This is a good style to make friends here.

Comment: Try this - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c0504284df4ec522f34f

Comment: The `long` type tops out at 19 digits. 4,000,000,000 isn't gonna happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with integers, you can convert a `long` into a `string` too, in order to get the n-th element

```
Dim numb As Long = 9876543210
Dim targetDigit As Integer = 3           ' Set target as the 3rd digit

numb.ToString()(targetDigit -1)          ' Retuns the 3rd digit: 7
```

---

**Side note:** I suspect that you may know this but, a `long` datatype can only hold

> Integers ranging in value from **-9,223,372,036,854,775,808** through **9,223,372,036,854,775,807**

That's only 19 digits! No where near 4 *billion*.

Source: [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y595sc15.aspx)